# Convert API request to text to use in site

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to make an API request and put the return in a div.. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast?pretty", false);
xhr.send();

xhr = function() {
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind onto the `onload` listener instead of setting a value to `xhr`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast?pretty", false);
xhr.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=this.responseText;
};
xhr.send();
```

See the MDN docs on Using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Thank you, does it matter if I use "this" instead of "xhr"

Comment: The `onload` function is run by the `XMLHttpRequest` so `this` will always equal `xhr` in this instance. It just means you could reuse that function for multiple `XMLHttpRequest`s and not have to reference a variable.

Comment: That's OK. You can still mark it as an answer by pressing the tick :)

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
xhr.onload = function() { //onload
   document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
}
```